# Image uploader not working

Tags: magento2, uploader

The upload image function recently broke on my backend after compiling. I'm running 2.2.7, but it has been an issue for over a year now. I've just haven't compiled until recently I was forced to. Any idea where I start troubleshooting?

I can select my file to upload, but it just returns to browse icon without any file uploaded.

Comment: Any error in browser console?

Comment: please share you code.

Comment: @Ali Ejaz What code do you want to see?
@BartZalas I do see 2 errors in the console

`4abd265af10e2dc756ec7fcc34a82ccc.min.js:120 GET https://www.hostas-store.com/pub/static/version1547590271/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/openVideoModal.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404`

And 

`VM1699:4 Error: Script error for: openVideoModal`

Comment: its a script issue
also, check your js files being compiled

Comment: @AliEjaz I just noticed my var/generation folder isn't being created. How do I check that the js files are being compiled?

Comment: Disabling module: Magento_ProductVideo has fixed my issue. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by disabling the module Magento_ProductVideo.